# Laptop with LinuxMint OS unable to detect external monitor

Tags: linux, linux-mint, nvidia, monitors, graphic-card

I had posted this in Superuser forum but did not got any response, so I am posting it here.

Laptop: Asus ROG Strix, G531GT-AL041T, G Core i7 9th Gen, with NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1650 graphics card. A Dell 22 inch Full HD Monitor (E2218HN) is connected with a HDMI cable. The external monitor worked well with the default Windows OS of the laptop, but not with Linux Mint 19.2 Tina OS. No signal is detected through the HDMI cable. Even in, Preferences -> Display, the laptop could not detect the external monitor display. I have also installed the recommended nvidia-430 driver. How do I get the HDMI-connected external monitor working? Please help. Here are some required information:

**inxi -Fxz**

```
System:    Host: brahman Kernel: 4.15.0-58-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 7.4.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.2.3 
           Distro: Linux Mint 19.2 Tina base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: Strix G531GT_G531GT v: 1.0 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: G531GT v: 1.0 serial: <filter> UEFI: American Megatrends v: G531GT.300 date: 04/19/2019 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 49.4 Wh condition: 49.4/50.5 Wh (98%) model: ASUSTeK ASUS Battery status: Not charging 
CPU:       Topology: 6-Core model: Intel Core i7-9750H bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Kaby Lake rev: A L2 cache: 12.0 MiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 62208 
           Speed: 899 MHz min/max: 800/4500 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 803 2: 845 3: 801 4: 854 5: 830 6: 830 7: 849 8: 838 
           9: 829 10: 853 11: 802 12: 817 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA vendor: ASUSTeK driver: N/A bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~120Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2) v: 4.5 Mesa 19.0.8 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
           Device-2: NVIDIA vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.1 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.15.0-58-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 5000 bus ID: 00:14.3 
           IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: ASUSTeK driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI 
           port: 3000 bus ID: 03:00.0 
           IF: eno2 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 26.03 GiB (5.5%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Intel model: SSDPEKNW512G8 size: 476.94 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 467.96 GiB used: 26.02 GiB (5.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 49.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 311 Uptime: 3h 30m Memory: 15.52 GiB used: 3.17 GiB (20.4%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 7.4.0 Shell: bash v: 4.4.20 inxi: 3.0.32
```

**grep HDMI /var/log/Xorg.0.log**

```
[     6.594] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event21)
[     6.945] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event16)
[     6.946] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event17)
[     6.946] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event18)
[     6.947] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event19)
[     6.947] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 (/dev/input/event20)
```

**inxi -SMCGx**

```
System:    Host: brahman Kernel: 4.15.0-58-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 7.4.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.2.3 
           Distro: Linux Mint 19.2 Tina base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: Strix G531GT_G531GT v: 1.0 serial: <root required> 
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: G531GT v: 1.0 serial: <root required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: G531GT.300 date: 04/19/2019 
CPU:       Topology: 6-Core model: Intel Core i7-9750H bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Kaby Lake rev: A L2 cache: 12.0 MiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 62208 
           Speed: 2801 MHz min/max: 800/4500 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 3276 2: 3353 3: 2717 4: 2728 5: 3287 6: 3006 7: 3346 
           8: 3201 9: 3302 10: 3563 11: 3292 12: 3336 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Device-2: NVIDIA vendor: ASUSTeK driver: N/A bus ID: 01:00.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~120Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2) v: 4.5 Mesa 19.0.8 direct render: Yes
```

**xrandr --prop**

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff003870420000000000
        011c0104a5221378036850985c588e28
        1b505400000001010101010101010101
        0101010101010b8380047138ca403020
        350058c21000001a6a3480047138ca40
        3020350058c21000001a000000fd0000
        000000000000202020202020000000fe
        004c4d3135364c462d474c30320a0042
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: Full, Center, Full aspect
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
   1920x1080    120.04*+  48.01
```

**ls /sys/class/drm**

```
card0 card0-eDP-1 renderD128 version
```

**xrandr --verbose**

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x44) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
    Identifier: 0x42
    Timestamp:  4528718
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.1:1.2
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff003870420000000000
        011c0104a5221378036850985c588e28
        1b505400000001010101010101010101
        0101010101010b8380047138ca403020
        350058c21000001a6a3480047138ca40
        3020350058c21000001a000000fd0000
        000000000000202020202020000000fe
        004c4d3135364c462d474c30320a0042
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: Full, Center, Full aspect
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
  1920x1080 (0x44) 335.470MHz +HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2180 skew    0 clock 153.89KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1282           clock 120.04Hz
  1920x1080 (0x45) 134.180MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2180 skew    0 clock  61.55KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1282           clock  48.01Hz
```

Comment: now i can see you have both an intel i915 and an nvidia 1650 GPU.   Have you installed bumblebee?  btw, see [Bumblebee Multi-monitor setup](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Multi-monitor-setup).   See also [Do not manage to activate HDMI on a laptop (that has optimus / bumblebee)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321151/do-not-manage-to-activate-hdmi-on-a-laptop-that-has-optimus-bumblebee).   Also, it looks like you haven't installed or loaded the `nvidia` device driver module (which should be available as a -dkms package for mint)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97759/discussion-between-vikash-and-cas).

Comment: I found the answer myself. The solution is: Enter the Bios, and disable the option for secure boot. Hurrah!